# Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined' typescript

Tags: typescript

I know there are a lot of other questions asking the same thing but I think the typescript compiler is just confused because

```
if(typeof this[method] === "function"){
    await this[method](req,res,next)
}
```

is giving me the following error: `Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'`. I thought typescript was supposed to be smart in the fact that it should know if you use typeguards to not throw errors like this. I've also tried ternary operators, if(this[method]), if(this[method]!==undefined), and all of them give me the same error.

For context:

```
for (const type of this.types){
    const method = type.toLowerCase() as Lowercase<Method>
    this.router[method](this.renderLocation, async (req, res, next) => {
        if(typeof this[method] === "function"){
            await this[method](req,res,next)
        }
    })
}
```

this is the entire block and Method is a type with the following definition:

```
export type Method =
    "POST" |
    "GET" |
    "PUT" |
    "DELETE"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript is not able to remember that the `this[method]` in your type check refers to the `this[method]` where it is being called. It's a brand new index on both occasions. It's like calling `.map` on an array without saving the result to a variable - the type might be valid but there's no way to use it.

However, once you assign the indexed method to a variable, the type check will be remembered:

```
const m = this[method];

if (typeof m === "function") {
  m(req, res, next);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much this worked, didn't realize that was the case. Now that I think about it, it does make sense.